# Can't I use annotation to indicate a bean is a primary bean

Tags: java, spring, annotations, autowired

We know in Spring, <bean> has an attribute "primary" to indicate a bean is the first candidate if there are multiple beans are available to be autowired to a property.

But now all my bean definition are declared using @Component/@Service, etc, I can't find the corresponding "primary" attribute I can use to declare a bean.

Please advise how can I achieve this, thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Spring 3.0, you use [`@Primary`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html).

> Indicates that a bean should be given
>   preference when multiple candidates
>   are qualified to autowire a
>   single-valued dependency. If exactly
>   one 'primary' bean exists among the
>   candidates, it will be the autowired
>   value.
>
> May be used on any class directly or
>   indirectly annotated with Component or
>   on methods annotated with Bean.
>
> Using Primary at the class level has
>   no effect unless component-scanning is
>   being used. If a Primary-annotated
>   class is declared via XML, Primary
>   annotation metadata is ignored, and
>   `<bean primary="true|false"/>` is
>   respected instead.

See [ref docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#new-java-configuration).

Comment: looks like your ref doc has died. this might be better: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html

Comment: Is there something like `@Secondary`? I have some legacy tests where I would like to quick fix the bean hell

Answer (score 4):

The @Primary annotation will only work if you are using Spring 3.0.

In Spring 2.5 there's no equivalent annotation for the primary attribute. You have to use the @Qualifier annotation to specify which bean you want to inject. Another option is to define your own qualifier annotation for the same purpose.

See the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) for more information.