# How to bind an interface to a specific implementation based on external config in java spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I want to read from a json config file on program startup time whether to use a Mongo db backend or a postgres backend. Based on this config, I then want to inject the respective service to the controller.

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IItemsService {

    public void putItem();

}
```

And two classes which implement it:

```
public class MongoItemsService implements IItemsService 
{
    private SomeMongoConnection conn;

    public MongoItemsService (SomeMongoConnection conn)
    {
         this.conn = conn;
    }

    @Override
    public void putItem() {
        System.out.println("Mongo");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class PostgresItemsService implements IItemsService 
{
    private SomePostgresConnection conn;

    public PostgresItemsService(SomePostgresConnection conn)
    {
         this.conn = conn;
    }

    @Override
    public void putItem() {
        System.out.println("Postgres");
    }
}
```

I finally have a controller which I want to inject into:

```
@RestController
public class ItemsController {

    private IItemsService itemsService;

    @RequestMapping("/putitem")
        public void putItem() {
        this.itemsService.putItem();
    }

    @Autowired
    public ItemsController(IItemsService itemsService)
    {
        this.itemsService = itemsService;
    }
}
```

So, based on the json config, I want to inject the respective IItemsService to the controller's constructor. I would like to avoid using annotations on the individual interface and implemented services class since they may be used in other projects which do not have a strict dependency on spring. How would I dynamically set the binding of the interface to concrete class at startup time?

Comment: make use of @primary or primary attribute in xml . Refer below links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998447/cant-i-use-annotation-to-indicate-a-bean-is-a-primary-bean  .Spring doc :  http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html

Comment: Wouldn't that indicate some sort of default? In this case, I don't think either of the service is a default/more preferential. I was doing a bit more research, and it seems like using profiles is also an option?

Comment: @user3517454 using of profiles will be best solutions for this case

Comment: yes you can load profile specific beans but keep in mind that other applications also need to enable that profile . if you enable primary only it will get injected into the controller if it finds two beans of same type.